Are these two CMake expressions equivalent for adding compile flags?
Let's just say I want to add compile flags to the Debug version, can I do either:
macro(append_compiler_flags_debug FLAGS)
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${FLAGS}")
endmacro()

append_compiler_flags_debug("/fsanitize=address" "/fsanitize=fuzzer")

versus:
add_compile_options(
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=address>
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=fuzzer>
    )

Are these pretty much equivalent?

Your append_compiler_flags_debug macro processes only the first parameter passed to it. That is, flag /fsanitize=address  will be added to CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG variables, but /fsanitize=fuzzer won't be added.
